# Rails 5 Checkbox filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to find a simple solution to this anywhere.  Simply put, I just want to be able to filter items with checkboxes and have the option to select multiple boxes and the filter work.  The parameters get inputted, but the results don't appear (see below).

If I remove the [] from view, I can get single items to search but not multiples.  The [] encodes `%5B%5D` into the URL which I think is part of reason search won't work.  Please anyone who can help.

Controller:

```
@cars = if params[:colour_category]
          Car.where('colour_category LIKE ? OR design LIKE ?', "%#{params[:colour_category]}%", "%#{params[:design_category]}%")
        else
          Car.all
        end
```

View:

```
 <%= form_tag cars_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= check_box_tag('colour_category[]', "Yellow") %>
   <%= check_box_tag('colour_category[]', "Blue") %>
   <%= check_box_tag('design_category[]', "Luxury") %>
   <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

Example of parameters in server after doing a submit: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "colour_category"=>["Yellow", "Blue"], "commit"=>"Submit"}`

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution then try `Car.where('colour_category IN ? OR design IN ?', "%#{params[:colour_category]}%", "%#{params[:design_category]}%")`

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach, which chains different scope/filter methods based on the `params` values. I'm posting an example from one of my apps, you can adapt the same concept:

```rb
module Client::Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include PgSearch::Model

  included do
    scope :find_by_company, -> (company_id) { where(company_id: company_id) }

    pg_search_scope :search, against: %w( name ), using: {
      tsearch: { prefix: true }
    }
  end

  class_methods do
    def filter(params = {})
      relation = self
      relation = relation.search(params[:query]) if params.fetch(:query, false).present?
      relation = relation.find_by_company(params[:company_id]) if params.fetch(:company_id, false).present?
      relation.all
    end
  end
end
```

then in your controller:

```rb
@clients = Client.all.filter(query: 'John Smith', company_id: 4356)
```

You can add as many filter options into the `#filter` method, they'll only be applied if the relevant param key is present.

```rb
def filter(params = {})
  relation = self
  relation = relation.by_color_category(params[:color_category]) if param.fetch(:color_category, false).present?
  relation = relation.by_design_category(params[:design_category]) if param.fetch(:design_category, false).present?
  relation.all
end
```